# Getting very low FPS when building simple Unity game onto iOS and running it on my iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I have built a relatively simple game in unity 5.6.1f1 which should run seamlessly upon building it and running it on my iPhone. However, upon building it I noticed that the frame rate is very low. I have tried adjusting quite a few things although nothing seems to work. Any suggestions on how I could increase my framerate???

Comment: Almost certainly your draw counts are very high. For reasonable performance you will need to get it down under 100 (depending on exact device specs). Lower is better.

Comment: @Draco18s, yes I know that is the problem but how would I do that?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html

Comment: @Draco18s yes however my background and pretty much all my graphics are constantly moving so i can't use static batching

Comment: I can't explain dynamic batching and what breaks it in a comment.

Comment: Also, if you're using Unity's built in UI (the new one, not `OnGui()`), you might want to check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-oZa4Fb12U). There's also [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4YAY36xjwE) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYYdvtf2DhQ) dealing with mobile optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode has some good [Profiling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/LaunchingInstruments.html) tools.  Try the [Time Profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Instrument-TimeProfiler.html) and look at the Call Tree to see where your CPU is spending most of its time.